# How to properly sum elements of an array

Tags: c, if-statement, recursion

I'm running a recursion program that takes an array, prints out all values in the array, sums the values, and takes the average of the values but the values aren't being summed.

```
int sum(int Arr[], int num)
{
    int x = 0;
    int ans;

    if (x == num - 1)
        ans = Arr[x];
    else
        ans = Arr[x] + sum(Arr, x + 1);
    return (ans);
}
```

If I put in the values 1, 2, 3 I should get a sum of 6 and an average of 3.00 but instead, I get a sum of 2 and an average of 0.00

Comment: `Arr` is not an array but a pointer to `int`.

Comment: How does that fix anything?

Comment: It should make you aware that by calling `sum(Arr, x + 1)` you don't know any longer how big the memory is you're allowed to access.

Comment: Is there any specific reason why you're doing it with recursion? It's going to be way less performant than simply iterating over the array, also it's going to cause a stack overflow if the array is too big.

Comment: So how do I fix it?

Comment: it has to be recursion for class

Answer (score 0):

The sum (and average) of an array with 1 element is that element

```
if (n == 1) {
    return a[0]; 
}
```

otherwise, the sum is the first element added to the sum of the rest of the array

```
return a[0] + sum(a+1, n-1);
```

Now, you know the sum with the recursive approach, you already knew how many elements there were, so just divide to get the average

```
avg = sum(a, n) / n;
```

All together

```
#include <stdio.h>

double sum(double *arr, size_t n) {
    if (n == 1) return *arr;
    return *arr + sum(arr + 1, n - 1);
}

int main(void) {
    double x[] = {3.14159, 2.71828182, -1, 0.0000042, 2019};
    double ss = sum(x, 5);
    printf("sum: %g; avg %g\n", ss, ss / 5);
}
```

see [code running on idone](https://ideone.com/sARrVk)

Comment: Should have thought about counting *downwards* :/

Answer (score 0):

```
#define ARR_SIZE 3
    int sum(int Arr[], int index\*starting from 0*\)
{
    int ans;

    if (index == SIZE - 1)
        ans = Arr[index];
    else
        ans = Arr[index] +  sum(Arr, index + 1 );
    return (ans);
}
```

Comment if you have any more questions, Good Luck!

Comment: `int ans = 0; for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) ans += Arr[i]; return ans;` Avoid recursive functions when a procedural solution is available. (avoid allocating a complete function stack for each recursive call)

Comment: Your solution is the iterative, obvious solution. Because he tried to do it using recursion I gave him the right recursion solution...

Comment: No complaints, but it is worth pointing out the downside to recursive calls and the preference for a procedural solution if one exists.